# What visa do I need for an internship in Russia?

Tags: visas, russia

Typically, for an internship you need to have a business visa. But me being from Pakistan, the company had refused to issue me an invitation visa but may give a letter to showy purpose of travel.
Update 1: I'm currently a student and will be going for a summer internship through [profintern.com](http://profintern.com). My planned time of stay is about 4-6 weeks.

Comment: Are you sure this is a legitimate company and job?

Comment: You either need a student visa, if company is qualified for that, or a working visa, which can be hard to get. You need to provide more information about your situation.

Comment: Updated the information.